# Use Solve solutions as Function when there are multiple solutions on distinct domains

Tags: equation-solving, inverse-function

First, I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate. I am very new to wolfram, and I have tried many solutions found here without success.

For the context, I have at hand a method to produce successive tables. The first one, table 1a, gives a volumic mass (density) from p, a mass percentage in [0; 1] and t, the temperature at which p has been measured, in [-20; 40] (celsius). It is produced from a function of the header and the index, giving us the table values, which can be found at  https://www.oiml.org/en/publications/bulletin/pdf/oiml_bulletin_july_2015.pdf, page 11 (numbered 9 in the doc) :

```
table1a[p_, t_] := 998.20123  - 192.9769495 * p + 389.1238958 * p ^ 2- 1668.103923 * p ^ 3+ 13522.15441 * p ^ 4- 88292.78388 * p ^ 5+ 306287.4042 * p ^ 6- 613838.1234 * p ^ 7+ 747017.2998 * p ^ 8- 547846.1354 * p ^ 9+ 223446.0334 * p ^ 10- 39032.85426 * p ^ 11- 0.20618513 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 0.0052682542 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 0.000036130013 * (t - 20) ^ 3- 0.00000038957702 * (t - 20) ^ 4+ 0.000000007169354 * (t - 20) ^ 5- 0.000000000099739231 * (t - 20) ^ 6+ 0.1693443461530087 * p ^ 1 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 10.46914743455169 * p ^ 2 * (t - 20) ^ 1+ 71.96353469546523 * p ^ 3 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 704.7478054272792 * p ^ 4 * (t - 20) ^ 1+ 3924.090430035045 * p ^ 5 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 12101.64659068747 * p ^ 6 * (t - 20) ^ 1+ 22486.46550400788 * p ^ 7 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 26055.62982188164 * p ^ 8 * (t - 20) ^ 1+ 18523.73922069467 * p ^ 9 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 7420.201433430137 * p ^ 10 * (t - 20) ^ 1+ 1285.617841998974 * p ^ 11 * (t - 20) ^ 1- 0.0119301300505701 * p ^ 1 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 0.2517399633803461 * p ^ 2 * (t - 20) ^ 2- 2.170575700536993 * p ^ 3 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 13.53034988843029 * p ^ 4 * (t - 20) ^ 2- 50.29988758547014 * p ^ 5 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 109.635566657757 * p ^ 6 * (t - 20) ^ 2- 142.2753946421155 * p ^ 7 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 108.043594285623 * p ^ 8 * (t - 20) ^ 2- 44.14153236817392 * p ^ 9 * (t - 20) ^ 2+ 7.442971530188783 * p ^ 10 * (t - 20) ^ 2- 0.0006802995733503803 * p ^ 1 * (t - 20) ^ 3+ 0.01876837790289664 * p ^ 2 * (t - 20) ^ 3- 0.2002561813734156 * p ^ 3 * (t - 20) ^ 3+ 1.02299296671922 * p ^ 4 * (t - 20) ^ 3- 2.895696483903638 * p ^ 5 * (t - 20) ^ 3+ 4.810060584300675 * p ^ 6 * (t - 20) ^ 3- 4.672147440794683 * p ^ 7 * (t - 20) ^ 3+ 2.458043105903461 * p ^ 8 * (t - 20) ^ 3- 0.5411227621436812 * p ^ 9 * (t - 20) ^ 3+ 0.000004075376675622027 * p ^ 1 * (t - 20) ^ 4- 0.00000876305857347111 * p ^ 2 * (t - 20) ^ 4+ 0.000006515031360099368 * p ^ 3 * (t - 20) ^ 4- 0.00000151578483698721 * p ^ 4 * (t - 20) ^ 4- 0.00000002788074354782409 * p ^ 1 * (t - 20) ^ 5+ 0.00000001345612883493354 * p ^ 2 * (t - 20) ^ 5
```

the second one, table 1b, is a variation of table 1a. With he same inputs, it gives the alcohol percentage q in [0; 100] of the solution from the mass percentage p and temperature of measurement of p, t. Its definition is as follows :

```
table1b[p_, t_] := 100 * p * table1a[p, t] / table1a[p, 1]
```

Table 2 is used to get from alcohol percentage and temperature of measurement to the volumic mass at this temperature. The official protocol is to get a mass percentage at 20C by doing a reverse search in table 1b for t=20, then apply table 1a. It makes no sense to me, but it's what legal doc say, so I do it. Doing this reverse search is only needed because we don't know the inverse function of table 1b. Big brain time, let's use mathematica to get it, and get rid of the need of tables, to get just one equation to apply!

```
table1b20[p_] := table1b[p, 20]
revTable1b20[q_] := p /. NSolve[{q == table1b20[p], 0<= p <=1.1}, {p}, Reals][[1]]
table2[q_, t_]:= table1a[revTable1b20[q], t]
```

I know there is a unique solution for revTable1b20 because table 1b columns are all strictly monotonic in the interval at hands.
Warning : I allowed p to go up to 1.1 instead of 1 such that q can go to 100 in the following table.

Now the hard part, table 8b. This table is used to go from an alcohol percentage q measured at temperature t, to an alcohol percentage at 20C. The protocol is to get the volumic mass of a solution which would have the same tav but at 20C by doing a reverse search in table 2, column 20, then get the volumic mass at t with a magic formula, then reverse search table 2 in column t with this volumic mass at t to get alcohol percentage. Again, not how I would have done it, but here it is:

```
revTable2[mv_, t_ ] := q /. Values[Solve[{mv == table2[q, t], 0<=q<=100, -20 <=t<=40}, {q},Reals]][[1]]
table8[q_, t_] := revTable2[table2[q, 20] * (1 -0.000025 * (t -20)), t]
```

Now,I know that for each t, table 2 can be reversed, as it is monotonic in this column. But of course the `Solve` in revTable2 gives multiple solutions (so the `[[1]]` is false). I guess each solution in the list depends on t, but I don't know how to tell mathematica to choose between the solutions thanks to t.

Bonus, here is how I would have computed table 2 and table 8 instead of those odd legal ways (that is, the logic behind it, not the actual code, since I face the same problem of multiple solutions depending on t that I don't know how to apply):

```
revTable1b[q_, t_] := p /. Solve[{q == table1b[p, t], 0<= p <=1, -20 <= t <=40}, {p}, Reals][[1]]
table2 [q_, t_] := table1a[revTable1b[q, t], t]
revTable2[mv_, t_ ] := q /. Values[Solve[{mv == table2[q, t], 0<=q<=100, -20 <=t<=40}, {q},Reals]][[1]]
table8 [q, t] := revTable2[table2[q, t], 20]
```

Comment: Hi! You did not provide `table1b20`, I am guessing `table1b20[p_]:=table1b[p,20]`. You can use `NSolve` instead of `Solve` to avoid the warning. Also, the max value of 1b is `table1b[1,20]` which gives `97.997`, therefore the error message for `table2[98, 40]` is expected I think. To plot replace `Plot3D[table2,...]` by `Plot3D[table2[q,t],...]`. It is not good style to use `revTable1b20` both as a function name and as a variable, even when it works, this kind of thing can bite you.

Comment: you are right about table 1b20. I'm updating the question about the function name as variable. as for the Nsolve instead of solve, I'm not sure where I should do that?

Comment: The whole process is about not doing Interpolation but using exact formula instead, and not having to produce tables to interpolate from, but getting the value by applying a function, so using `Interpolation` would take me back to square one. As I already have a python code that does just that.

Comment: Thank you for helping me tidy up my question!
Now the real question is how do I get revTable2 to work? I hope it's just a wolfram language noob question?

Comment: Try `revTable2[mv_,t_]:=Module[{q},q/.Solve[{mv==table2[q,t],0<=q<=100},q][[1]]]`, which is more or less what you have already. With say `revTable2[900,15]` I get `56.9373`, perhaps you can check if that is plausible. Btw, not sure anymore if my previous suggestion to switch to `NSolve` was a great idea, perhaps `Solve` uses a more useful method.

Comment: Oh yes it seems that was the solution! would you mind explaining it? I've read the doc for "Module" but even knowing the result it doesn't really help to know what it really does

Comment: The `Module[{q},...]` is just good coding practice I would say, it makes `q` a local variable to avoid problems in case you defined `q` elsewhere. But provided you have not defined `q` elsewhere, then `revTable2` should work even when when you remove `Module[{q},...]`.